# onPress fires immediately in ListItem when there is a short touch in the Lists

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

React Native Elements Version  -  0.19.1,
React Native - 0.57.8

I have been using React Native elements for building a settings Screens, and its working very well. But , i have used Card and List Item to bring up a list view inside card view. Here is the code for List View inside Card View.

```
<View style = { styles.settingsCardContainerStyle }>
                <Card>
                    {
                        list.map((item, i) => (
                        <ListItem
                            key={i}
                            title={item.name}
                            leftIcon={{ name: item.icon }}
                            onPress= {() => this.props.navigation.navigate(item.screenName)}
                            activeOpacity={0.7}
                            containerStyle= {{
                                borderBottomWidth: 0.2,
                            }}

                        />
                        ))
                    }
                </Card>
            </View>
```

And list is correctly rendering, the actual problem is when ever i do a swipe or scroll or something , the onpress fires immediately. In Other words, if i do a natural scroll on the list view the first item will trigger on fire. How to delay the on press event for 0.5 sec. When i used onLongpress it works correctly but it takes at least more than 1 sec to work. I tried to reduce the longpres duration but doesn't seems to work.

What should i do now, is there any way to delay onpress event for few mill sec, or how to decrease onlongpress for 0.3 or 0.4 milli seconds, which will match normal user usage or touch.

Answer (score 0):

use debounce of lodash js

```
()=> debounce(function() {
this.props.navigation.navigate(item.screenName)}, 300);
```

Comment: debounce is for preventing double touch or etc ! i am asking solution for slowing the firing process of onpres